# Duvida ao criar tabela com datas no postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu precisaria criar uma 3° tabela que ficaria da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho a menor e a maior data em uma tabela e em outra tabela eu tenho alterações feitas, eu precisaria criar um script que geraria uma 3° tabela, criando os intervalos dos valores.

```
Obs: A coluna id é um AUTOINCREMENTO.
```

Se formos transformar em palavras, ficaria assim:

> Entre os dias 05-06-2018 até 19-06-2018 o valor era 50.
>
> Entre os dias 19-06-2018 até 21-06-2018 o valor era 150.
>
> Entre os dias 21-06-2018 até 25-06-2018 o valor era 180.
>
> Entre os dias 25-06-2018 até 05-07-2018 o valor era 200.

Pensei em usar `WHILE` e variáveis, mas não consegui completar o script. Como isso poderia ser feito? Não parece ser algo tão complexo, mas eu acabei não conseguindo.

Comment: da onde surgiu o id 4 ?... pra q tem id na tabela1 ? ele se relaciona ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis A coluna "id" é apenas um autoincremento na tabela, não se relacionam entre si, é apenas um coluna para auxiliar caso seja necessario buscar um valor especifico.

Comment: me parece que esses dados da tabela 1 deveriam ser apenas parametros da consulta... e de onde surgiu o id 4 no resultado ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis De fato, são apenas parametros. O id 4 é apenas um identificador para aquela linha, não tem relacionamento com outros ids, ele apareceu por ser um autoincremento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver o seu problema usando uma [`Window Function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_window_function) chamada [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) combinada com um [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html).

Assumindo que suas tabelas sejam algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_tabela1
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data DATE
);

INSERT INTO
  tb_tabela1 ( id, data )
VALUES
  ( 1, '2018-06-05' ),
  ( 2, '2018-07-05' );

CREATE TABLE tb_tabela2
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  dataAlteracao DATE,
  valorAnterior INTEGER,
  valorAtual INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO
  tb_tabela2 ( id, dataAlteracao, valorAnterior, valorAtual )
VALUES
  ( 1, '2018-06-19', 50, 150 ),
  ( 2, '2018-06-21', 150, 180 ),
  ( 3, '2018-06-25', 180, 200 );
```

Sua query ficaria assim:

```
(SELECT
   dataAlteracao AS dataInicio,
   lead(dataAlteracao,1,(SELECT max(data) FROM tb_tabela1)) OVER (ORDER BY dataAlteracao) AS dataFim,
   valorAtual AS valor
 FROM
    tb_tabela2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
   (SELECT min(data) FROM tb_tabela1),
   dataAlteracao,
   valorAnterior
 FROM
   tb_tabela2 ORDER BY dataAlteracao LIMIT 1
) ORDER BY dataFim;
```

Saída:

```
| datainicio |    datafim | valor |
|------------|------------|-------|
| 2018-06-05 | 2018-06-19 |    50 |
| 2018-06-19 | 2018-06-21 |   150 |
| 2018-06-21 | 2018-06-25 |   180 |
| 2018-06-25 | 2018-07-05 |   200 |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3872/10)

Para inserir seus dados em uma terceira tabela, você pode fazer algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_tabela3
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  dataInicio DATE,
  dataFim DATE,
  valor INTEGER
);
```

Inserindo os dados:

```
INSERT INTO tb_tabela3 ( dataInicio, dataFim, valor ) (
(SELECT
   dataAlteracao AS dataInicio,
   lead(dataAlteracao,1,(SELECT max(data) FROM tb_tabela1)) OVER (ORDER BY dataAlteracao) AS dataFim,
   valorAtual AS valor
 FROM
    tb_tabela2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
   (SELECT min(data) FROM tb_tabela1),
   dataAlteracao,
   valorAnterior
 FROM
   tb_tabela2 ORDER BY dataAlteracao LIMIT 1
));
```

Testando:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_tabela3 ORDER BY dataInicio;
```

Saída:

```
| id | datainicio |    datafim | valor |
|----|------------|------------|-------|
|  1 | 2018-06-05 | 2018-06-19 |    50 |
|  2 | 2018-06-19 | 2018-06-21 |   150 |
|  3 | 2018-06-21 | 2018-06-25 |   180 |
|  4 | 2018-06-25 | 2018-07-05 |   200 |
```

Veja funcionando no [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/76468/4)

Comment: Sua resposta funcionou perfeitamente, eu apenas gostaria de tirar uma duvida: Teria como explicar como essa linha está trabalhando? `lead(dataAlteracao,1,(SELECT max(data) FROM tb_tabela1)) OVER (ORDER BY dataAlteracao) AS dataFim,`. Não sabia desses usos do `LEAD` e nem do `OVER` sem o partition.

Comment: @Thatcher: `lead()` retorna o próximo registro em relação ao atual, caso ele não exista, o `SELECT Max()` é usado como default.

Answer (score -1):

Como citei nos comentários, não vejo o porque da tabela1, me parece apenas parâmetro da consulta.

De qualquer forma, utilizei apenas a data menor pra ser exibida como inicial do primeiro registro.

A query é bem simples: Definindo DataAlteracao sendo a DataFim do registro, e a DataInicio sendo a maior data do registro anterior, basta fazer um sub-select:

```
SELECT t.id,
       coalesce(
                  (SELECT max(x.dataAlteracao)
                   FROM tabela2 x
                   WHERE x.id < t.id),
                  (SELECT min(DATA)
                   FROM tabela1)) AS data_inicio,
       t.dataAlteracao,
       t.valorAnterior,
       t.ValorAtual
FROM tabela2 t
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b97a6/4)

Comment: Sua consulta não retorna o ultimo registro: o período de `2018-06-25` até `2018-07-05` não está no retorno.